# html5 incompatible browser testing

Tags: javascript, html, css, modernizr

I use **modernizr** to support some html5 features (like placeholder or different input types such as date, number) for my website. However, the current browsers in my **mac** (chrome and safari) support html5 and I don't have any chance to test my website in a browser that doesn't have html5 support.

What's the best approach to test a website under the non-html5 conditions? Downloading an html5 incompatible browser (if so example please) or a tool ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're on Mac (so am I), the images provided through modern.ie might be more helpful. They have vm images for VirtualBox and VMWare, in addition to VirtualPC.

Comment: I guess this is the first thing I like by Microsoft. Accepted the answer thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft offers virtual machines for testing Internet Explorer versions: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Browsershots](https://browsershots.org/) could be of help to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't have any chance to test hover/click etc events with this.